# Getting 403 Forbidden When Uploading file using Google Drive API in Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Here is how the code in my DriveQuickstart.java looks like:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FOLDER = "credentials"; // Directory to store user credentials.

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_DIR = "client_secret.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If there is no client_secret.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_DIR);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(CREDENTIALS_FOLDER)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
//        FileList result = service.files().list()
//                .setPageSize(10)
//                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
//                .execute();
//        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
//        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
//            System.out.println("No files found.");
//        } else {
//            System.out.println("Files:");
//            for (File file : files) {
//                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
//            }
//        }

        //List all the Google Docs files
//        String pageToken = null;
//        do {
//            FileList result = service.files().list()
//                    .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document'")
//                    .setSpaces("drive")
//                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
//                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
//                    .execute();
//            for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
//                System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
//                        file.getName(), file.getId());
//            }
//            pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
//        } while (pageToken != null);

        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
        File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
    }
}
```

I modified the Google Drive API quickstart code and added a bit of Java code from the "Uploading Files" section of the API documentation. I copied the code as it is but I am getting the following error in the console of my IDE:

```
Apr 22, 2018 11:18:25 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Tutorial\Java\google-api\credentials
Apr 22, 2018 11:18:25 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Tutorial\Java\google-api\credentials
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:100)
```

I was unable to find a solution to my specific problem anywhere else and those that I found didn't work for me. I tried finding some Youtube videos to accomplish this uploading task using Java but didn't find any. How can I fix this issue and get my program to upload a file?

Can any one give my the Java code for accomplishing this task so that I can analyze and use it as reference for my further coding tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Drive API Quickstarts, remember to change the scope according to type of your request - you're doing a [WRITE request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#auth) for this instance.

Atleast one of this should be enabled:

```
Scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

Don't forget to delete your previously saved credentials for the new scopes to take effect.